# Does it make sense to do npm install if a package has no dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

Let's say I have an npm package which has no dependencies, because I bundled all the source files and dependencies into one file using webpack. I download this package and unpack it into `./my‑awesome‑package/` directory. Does it make sense to run `npm install ./my-awesome-package/` now?

I know that you can specify `preinstall` and `postinstall` scripts in `package.json`, but except that, does `npm install` actually do anything when there are no dependencies?

Comment: "because I bundled all the source files and dependencies into one file using webpack" don't do that. If everybody did this we wouldn't even need npm and my hard drive would be full of redundant content in multiple files all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you wouldn't need to as there is nothing to do for npm anyway.

But if you are setting up a more general flow, you might want to add and forget about it. If you don't use it, you will always need to remember that you don't have it (you might add some dependency in the future and wonder why it wont work all the sudden).